# Python find continuous interesctions of intervals

Tags: python, intersection

I tired multiple approaches, but failed to do this one job. All of them use only 2 lists or range of lists.
The one most promising was:

```
infile = open('file','r')

for line in infile:
    line = line.split()
    f = range(int(line[0]),int(line[1]))

results_union = set().union(*f)
print results_union
```

I have a file with start,end positions like this: (sorted)

```
1 5
1 3
1 2
2 4
3 6
9 11
9 16
12 17
```

I would like the output to be:

```
1 6
9 17
```

Comment: So, you're trying to group contiguous segments in the range of the input?

Comment: yes. And i only want to know start-end of those segments, thus, their lengths

Comment: This is the union of the given intervals, not the intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
def group(data):
    data = sorted(data)
    it = iter(data)
    a, b = next(it)
    for c, d in it:
        if b >= c:  # Use `if b > c` if you want (1,2), (2,3) not to be
                    # treated as intersection.
            b = max(b, d)
        else:
            yield a, b
            a, b = c, d
    yield a, b


with open('file') as f:
    data = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f]

for a, b in group(data):
    print a, b
```

Example:

```
>>> data = (9,16), (1,5), (1,3), (1,2), (3,6), (9,11), (12,17), (2,4),
>>> list(group(data))
[(1, 6), (9, 17)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This following looks promising. The first part is based on your approach. The second part just looks for contiguous intervals in the union of ranges.

```
intervals = []
with open('contigous_input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        start, stop = sorted(map(int, line.split()))
        intervals.append(range(start, stop+1))

union = list(set().union(*intervals))
print union

results = []
i = start = 0
j = i + 1
while j < len(union):
    if union[j] != union[i]+1:
        results.append( (union[start], union[j-1]) )
        if j == len(union):
            break
        i = start = j
        j = i + 1
    else:
        i, j = j, j + 1

if start != j-1:
    results.append( (union[start], union[j-1]) )

print results
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[(1, 6), (9, 17)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2-tuples instead of the `range` function, because `range` returns a `list`. Here's a simple function that will combine two of your 2-tuples if possible:

```
def combine_bounds(x, y):
  a, b = sorted([x, y])
  if a[1]+1 >= b[0]:
    return (a[0], max(a[1],b[1]))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> combine_bounds((1,2), (3,4))
(1, 4)
>>> combine_bounds((1,100), (3,4))
(1, 100)
>>> combine_bounds((1,2), (4,10))
>>> combine_bounds((1,3), (4,10))
(1, 10)
>>> combine_bounds((1,6), (4,10))
(1, 10)
>>> combine_bounds((10,600), (4,10))
(4, 600)
>>> combine_bounds((11,600), (4,10))
(4, 600)
>>> combine_bounds((9,600), (4,10))
(4, 600)
>>> combine_bounds((1,600), (4,10))
(1, 600)
>>> combine_bounds((12,600), (4,10))
>>> combine_bounds((12,600), (4,10)) is None
True
```

`None` is a falsey value in Python, so you can use the result of `combine_bounds` in conditionals. If it returns `None` (similar to `False`), then there was no intersection. If it returns a 2-tuple, then there was an intersection and the return value is the result.

I didn't do all the work for you (you still need to figure out how to use this on the input to get your desired output), but this should get you going in the right direction!