# Python Nested list -Time intervals - intersection and difference

Tags: python, datetime, intervals

I have a problem with a nested list, time as elements

```
time=[(2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z,2017-01-01T00:00:39.820000Z),
(2017-01-01T00:00:38.840000Z,2017-01-01T01:36:33.260000Z),
(2017-01-01T01:36:45.960000Z,2017-01-01T03:06:15.340000Z),
(2017-01-01T03:06:24.320000Z,2017-01-01T03:31:00.420000Z),
(2017-01-01T03:31:22.880000Z,2017-01-01T03:48:43.500000Z),
(2017-01-01T03:48:53.280000Z,2017-01-01T04:14:53.660000Z),
(2017-01-01T04:15:15.160000Z,2017-01-01T04:34:44.060000Z),
(2017-01-01T04:34:57.440000Z,2017-01-01T04:46:31.100000Z),
(2017-01-01T04:46:53.320000Z,2017-01-01T05:22:20.340000Z),
(2017-01-01T05:22:24.920000Z,2017-01-01T06:17:30.900000Z),
(2017-01-01T06:18:02.280000Z,2017-01-01T07:01:45.740000Z),
(2017-01-01T07:02:04.640000Z,2017-01-01T07:39:48.780000Z),
(2017-01-01T07:40:12.400000Z,2017-01-01T08:19:46.140000Z),
(2017-01-01T08:20:13.520000Z,2017-01-01T10:17:45.380000Z),
(2017-01-01T10:17:59.880000Z,2017-01-01T15:01:29.100000Z),
(2017-01-01T15:01:55.840000Z,2017-01-01T15:08:45.460000Z),
(2017-01-01T15:09:04.000000Z,2017-01-01T15:42:13.180000Z),
(2017-01-01T15:42:30.360000Z,2017-01-01T16:14:07.340000Z),
(2017-01-01T16:14:24.560000Z,2017-01-01T17:11:28.420000Z),
(2017-01-01T17:11:32.960000Z,2017-01-01T17:46:07.660000Z),
(2017-01-01T17:46:30.280000Z,2017-01-01T18:02:17.860000Z),
(2017-01-01T18:02:35.240000Z,2017-01-01T18:16:17.740000Z),
(2017-01-01T18:16:26.720000Z,2017-01-01T18:39:10.540000Z),
(2017-01-01T18:39:19.360000Z,2017-01-01T19:45:25.860000Z),
(2017-01-01T19:45:34.720000Z,2017-01-01T20:41:00.220000Z),
(2017-01-01T20:41:21.520000Z,2017-01-01T21:13:51.660000Z),
(2017-01-01T21:14:13.360000Z,2017-01-01T21:41:16.220000Z),
(2017-01-01T21:41:28.640000Z,2017-01-01T22:03:03.820000Z),
(2017-01-01T22:03:29.400000Z,2017-01-01T23:14:13.500000Z),
(2017-01-01T23:14:35.200000Z,2017-01-01T23:59:59.980000Z)]
```

as you can see, all the elements belong to the same day, 2017-01-01, what I want to do is the difference (in seconds or ms) of the entire day (86400s) and all the intervals in the list, but there are some overlaps, so I think that first I have to do some kind of "intersection check", and after all the intersections are set, just do the difference between all the elements and 86400, but how can I do that intersection check?. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Desired Output:
86400(day) - 85000(possible time in seconds after time intersection of list) = 1400

Comment: Please edit your post to include the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

- to replace overlapping intervals with their unions;
- to sum the resulting non-overlapping intervals.

The first part can be done like this:

```
time.sort()
new_time = [list(time[0])]
for t in time[1:]:
    if t[0] <= new_time[-1][1]:
        if t[1] > new_time[-1][1]:
            new_time[-1][1] = t[1]
    else:
        new_time.append(list(t))
```

while the second part is best done using `datetime` module:

```
import datetime

total = sum([ ( datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') -
                datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') ).total_seconds()
              for t in new_time ])

print(86400 - total)
```

Comment: works nicely, tried changing some values with even bigger overlaps and it worked really nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After converting strings to numbers, you could use the top answer from [Python find continuous interesctions of intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745693/python-find-continuous-interesctions-of-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and then merge any overlaps

```
time.sort()
noOverlapList = []
start = time[0][0] # start of first interval
end = time[0][1] # end of first interval
for interval in time:
    # if interval overlaps with tempInterval
    if interval[0] < end and interval[1] > end:
            end = interval[1]
    else if interval[0] > end:
        noOverlapList.append((start, end)) # merged non overlapping interval
        start = interval[0]
        end = interval[1]
```

Then just sum the intervals contained in `noOverlaplList`, and get the difference

Comment: No need for a lambda here - tuples are sorted in lexicographic order.

Comment: Another problem is, what happens if one interval is completely within another, so that `interval[0] < end` is true, but `interval[1] > end` is not? I think my solution covers this case.

Comment: Yeah forgot the else if.