# Real spent time between several range of datetime

Tags: python-3.x

I have a lot of records with these values:

```
id      start              end
1       2019-01-01 08:00   2019-01-01 09:00
2       2019-01-01 08:30   2019-01-01 09:15
3       2019-01-02 19:00   2019-01-02 19:15
...
```

Real spent time is 90m for the 3 first records.

I easily can calculate real spent time if range datetime intersects by calculating de min and de max time.

But how can easily calculate real spent time if records can intersect and not intersect?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution is this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746503/12845160

Example:

```
date_ranges = [
('2020-01-10 14:39:05', '2020-01-10 14:47:45'), 
('2020-01-10 14:11:27', '2020-01-10 14:39:05'), 
('2020-01-10 14:11:09', '2020-01-10 14:47:45'), 
('2020-01-10 12:44:41', '2020-01-10 13:00:55'), 
('2020-01-10 12:44:33', '2020-01-10 13:51:50'),
]
```

And the solution is:

```
>>> list(group(date_ranges))
[
('2020-01-10 12:44:33', '2020-01-10 13:51:50'), 
('2020-01-10 14:11:09', '2020-01-10 14:47:45'),
]
```

Union of the max interval of the date ranges given.

Thanks @falsetru